# How do I make a toggleable Infrared motion detection module

Tags: arduino-uno

I just got an Arduino and an Infrared motion detection module. What I tried making is, that if the module detected movement, a led would turn on, and if it detected movement again, it would turn off. So I wrote this code and tried looking online for solutions, but couldn't find it. I really don't know what to change about my code to make it work. Does anyone have solutions for this?

(Sensor value can be 0 or 1, 0 means nothing detected, 1 means something detected. After detection the value automatically goes back to 0 in a few seconds)

```
int Sensor = 4;
int led = 13;
bool bool1 = false;

void setup() {
pinMode(Sensor, INPUT);
pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
int SensorValue = digitalRead(Sensor);

if(SensorValue == 1){
  bool1 = !bool1;
  }

if(bool1 == true){
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
  }
if(bool1 == false){
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);
  }
}
```

Comment: `what to change about my code to make it work`  .... what is wrong with the way the code behaves right now?

Answer (score 2):

Consider using a [state machine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine) with 4 states.  Currently you only have 2 states.  One where "bool1" is TRUE and another when "bool1" is FALSE.  The 4 states needed are:

1. When the LED is OFF & the [PIR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_infrared_sensor) is NOT-ACTIVE.
2. When the LED is OFF & the PIR is ACTIVE.
3. When the LED is ON and the PIR is ACTIVE.
4. When the LED is ON and the PIR is NOT-ACTIVE.

As you travel between these 4 states, you will find you only want to turn the LED ON when traveling between states 2 & 3.  And you will only want to turn the LED OFF when traveling between states 4 & 1.